# Trying to call two functions within function PHP

Tags: php, function, scope

I feel like this is a dumb question, but I can't figure it out.

I have a php file that needs to ping the database a minimal amount of times. I have two functions that use the same data from the ping and I'm trying to call those functions within one function.

Each function loops over the mysql query result and checks a different condition, it calls another function if a condition is met. The problem is once the first function is finished being executed the second function does not get executed.

Please help.

```
function gather_info(){
$cash_request = check_user_cash_on_hand();
if($cash_request != false){
    check_for_overpay($cash_request);
    check_for_sabotage($cash_request);
}
}


function check_for_overpay($cash_requests){
if(mysql_num_rows($cash_requests) > 0){
    $days_possible_amount = get_days_ads_amount();
    if($days_possible_amount != false){
        $first_bucket = 1/3 * $days_possible_amount;
        $second_bucket = 2/3 * $days_possible_amount;
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($cash_requests)){
            $cash_id = $row["cash_id"];
            $cash_request = $row["CASH"];


            if($cash_request <= $first_bucket){
                echo "I'm in one";



            }else if($cash_request > $first_bucket && $cash_request <= $second_bucket){
                echo "I'm in two";

            }else if($cash_request > $second_bucket){
                notify_admin_of_suspicious_amount($row, "not_possible");

            }
        }
    }   
}   

}


/* CHECKS IF SUM OF CASH REQUESTS PER USER GREATER THAN 5 and LESS THAN OR EQUAL TO HIS EARNED AMOUNT */
function check_for_sabotage($cash_request){
if(mysql_num_rows($cash_request) > 0){
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($cash_request)){
        $requested_cash = $row["CASH"];
        $available_cash = $row["cash_amount"];

        if($requested_cash > 5 && $requested_cash <= $available_cash){
            echo "you got me";
        }else{
            notify_admin_of_suspicious_amount($row, "not_enough");
        }
    }
}   
}

function notify_admin_of_suspicious_amount($row, $type){

echo "suspicious";


}
```

Basically if check_for_overpay finishes the script stops and check_for_sabotage never gets called. Any suggestions?

Comment: Well, what does `check_for_overpay` do?

Comment: You can see in my question I explain what each function does.

Comment: Yeah, that's not what I was asking. How do you expect us to help you with code we can't see?

Comment: OK, I edited it to reflect that.

Comment: BASIC is a different programming language; please don't abuse the tag!

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `mysql_num_rows()` inside of your function `check_for_overpay()`. The connection that it needs, `mysql_connect()`, is likely outside of the variable scope for the function, since it's not being passed and no function making a connection is being called within that function.

Also note that `mysql_*` functions [have been deprecated as of PHP 5.5](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php). You should be using MySQLi or PDO.